# Ways to improve Gmail API speed (PHP)

Tags: php, performance, google-api, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API's PHP wrapper to first fetch a mail list and then get a few of each mail's header info with using its mail ID, but I have been experiencing very inconsistent & slow speeds with it. I am already using things like partial response and batch requests stated on Google's best practice page.

Below is a snapshot of the code I use

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$service= new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

//Call to get mail list from or to user email, limit to 10 result 
$messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', array('maxResults' => 10, 'q' => "from:$email OR to:$email"));
$messageList = $messages->getMessages();

//enable batch use for client
$client->setUseBatch(true);

//Loop through message list, add get mail request for each message to batch
foreach($messageList as $msg_obj){

    $request = $this->service->users_messages->get('me', $msg_obj->id,array('format' => 'metadata', 'metadataHeaders' => array('date','subject','to')));        
    $batch->add($request, "mail-".$msg_obj->id);

}
//Call batch
$results = $batch->execute();
```

Most of the first get list call takes 0.7 - 1.2 sec

The batch call takes around 1.7 - 3 sec

Despite using batch call and only fetching 'date', 'subject', 'to' header from each mail, the time of both calls can still take up to ~ 4 sec, which is very noticeable, and the speed of the calls are still very inconsistent. Without using partial response on the header, the speed was even more slow.

Is the speed im getting normal for Gmail API and are there ways I can get the speed down further?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could try with limit above 10 (try with 20)?  Using multiple threads is definitely the way to get the highest performance, but obviously there's some extra complexity (have say 1 thread doing list() and throwing msg-ids in a queue, then 4 threads reading off that queue and doing batched get()).

Whatever you do, if you're trying to maximize throughput make sure you handle 429 (rate limit exceeded) errors well.